# Android sql usable characters for creating table

Tags: android, sql

What are the not suggested characters the user can include in a table name?
I give the user the opportunity to create tables in my app, but I want to prevent force closes deriving from including bad characters in the table name.
What are these characters? Any how can I include them in an array?
e.g. `List<String> usable_chars = Arrays.asList(";", "'", "/");`
but it gives me an error for "\" and """, what is the right syntaxis for these in a list?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In java you will need to escape certain characters. 
See "Escape Sequences"
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html